# A phrase meaning "as frequently/often happens"?

Tags: phrase-request

I am looking for a phrase meaning "as frequently/often happens"?

---- , she believed it when she heard such sort of rumor.

Comment: Neither *frequently* nor *often happens* would fit into the blank spot in your sentence and have it make sense.

Comment: Usually ***as often happens*** refers to a fairly general statement. I'm not sure exactly what you mean by your (non-grammatical) statement ***when she believed it when she heard such sort of rumor***, but I'm guessing you might mean ***she** (in particular) believed that kind of rumour (when she heard it.* That might be better expressed as ***As she often did,** she believed it when she heard that kind of rumour*. Using ***as (so) often happens*** implies that ***people in general*** believe that kind of rumour (in which context *...when they hear it* seems like unnecessary verbiage to me).

Comment: As usual ? As always? As per usual?